# How to Pass textbox value using @html.actionlink in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to Pass value from text using @html.actionlink in asp.net mvc3 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than passing your value using @Html.actionlink, try jquery to pass your textbox value to the controller as:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: { search: $('#textboxid').val()},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#mydiv').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This code will post your textbox value to the controller and returns the output result which will be loaded in the div "mydiv".

Comment: The page doesn't refresh and needed to write an other method to refresh to refresh

Answer (score 19):

None of the answers here really work. The accepted answer doesn't refresh the page as a normal action link would; the rest simply don't work at all or want you to abandon your question as stated and quit using `ActionLink`.

**MVC3/4**

You can use the `htmlAttributes` of the `ActionLink` method to do what you want:

```
Html.ActionLink("My Link Title", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { onclick = "this.href += '&myRouteValueName=' + document.getElementById('myHtmlInputElementId').value;" })
```

**MVC5**

The following error has been reported, but I have not verified it:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected

Comment: If you get the dangerous Request.Path error in MVC5 or above this is due to enhanced security as & is not permitted in the URL by default.  You can add the below to your web.config file which will allow it (anytihing in the list is not allowed):

`<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=",*,%,:,\,?" />`

Answer (score 6):

to pass data from the client to the server you could use a html form:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName,controllerName)) {
    <input type="text" name="myText"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Check your value!">
}
```

be sure to catch your myText variable inside your controller's method

Comment: Should've included how you do that:  `string myText = Request.Form["myText"].Value;`

Answer (score -4):

you can use this code (YourValue = TextBox.Text)

```
Html.ActionLink("Test", new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", new { id = YourValue }, null );

public class YourController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult YourAction(int id)
        {
            return View("here your value", id);
        }
}
```

Comment: try with <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Property, new { id = "IdTextBox" })%>

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.name, new { id = "IdTextBox" })
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Create","Home",new{id=IdTextBox}),but it didn't work.:(